# Php/mysql some data refuses to insert

Tags: php

In my site's registration, the insert is only working for certain data, not sure why

heres the code (I know, no salt, I will fix that next)

```
if ($id == "0" || $id == null)
{   echo '<title>Start</title>';
    $content .= '
        <body><center>
            <h1>TitleBar</h1>
            <img src="logo.png" alt="Smiley face" height="400" width="400">
            <form action="?id=loginF" method="POST">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>LOGIN </legend>
            <p><label for="username">Username</label> <input type="text" name="username" required="required" autofocus="autofocus"/></p>
            <p><label for="password">Password</label> <input type="password" name="password" required="required"/></p>
            <p class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Login"/></p>
            </fieldset>
            </form>

        </center>
    ';
    echo $content;
}
```

This next section is for after the form is submitted:

```
if ($id == "loginF")
        {
        echo '<title>Login</title>';
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $email = $_POST['username'];
        $snapchat = new Snapchat($username,$password);
         echo $username;
        $_SESSION['name'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['pass'] = $password;
        $ulz="INSERT INTO user_attribs(username,email,salted)VALUES('$username'
                    ,'$email','$password')";
        mysql_query($ulz);
        $content .= '
        <ul>
            <li><a href="?id=getSnaps">Get Snaplist</a></li>
            <li><a href="?id=getFriends">Get Friendlist</a></li>
            <li><a href="?id=sendSnap">Send pics</a></li>
            <li><a href="?id=logout">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
        ';
        echo $content;

    }
```

for example:

top@kek.com with any password will insert as a username

however, any username with, for example, an @hotmail.com address will not insert

what could be the cause of that?

I tried to google it, I honestly have no idea.

EDIT::

**I want to be more specific in the error. I did some testing. The following CAN insert: hotmail.com, .hotmail.com, a@hotmail.com, art@hotmail.com, however, a.rt@hotmail.com cannot be inserted. it must be the front period.**

Comment: What is the size of the field username in your table ?

Comment: Is `session_start();` loaded anywhere?

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: session_start(); is line 2 of the document

Comment: ... and a probable solution to your problem - http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: can you be more specific? 1:20 am, and its like staring at heiroglphs right now

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the Snapchat API. Plus, you're using the same variable `$email = $_POST['username'];`  `username` --- `$username = $_POST['username'];` - Those two things combined, could be a factor.

Comment: Fred, at first I didn't have it like that. I used that as an attempt to get the data one way or another. Didn't work. Initially I set email to "EMPTY"

Comment: I'd look into the Snapchat API then. That's all I can come up with at this point.

Comment: @Fred-ii- How does the Snapchat api factors in? Op's not using the value returned by that at all. Also, the session_start() too can't be the issue here, since the problem is not sessions not being kept

Comment: I want to be more specific in the error. I did some testing. The following CAN insert: hotmail.com, .hotmail.com, a@hotmail.com, art@hotmail.com, however, a.rt@hotmail.com cannot be inserted. it must be the front period. WHY

Comment: @DamienPirsy It's called "Troubleshooting" questions.

Comment: Solved the problem, will answer below

Comment: Great, I'm real curious to know ;-) @user2962806

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the table description, username was VARCHAR(15)

This was what caused the problem. By extending the column length, I was able to get the data inserted.

Comment: Oh for crying outloud, I was actually going to mention that earlier, I should've followed my instinct on that one LOL!

Comment: Email addresses can be at times rather long. So it's best to have a larger than anticipated column length. I set everything to its full max when it comes to VARCHAR.